# Check if linklist is not empty before getNode method

Tags: java, jsp, aem, jcr

I have a sort of convoluted question. I'll try my best to explain. I am working on a Adobe CQ codebase that is JCR and Java-based.

I have a Java ArrayList declaration like this:

```
ArrayList<Map<String,Property>> list6 = new ArrayList<Map<String,Property>>();
```

Furthermore I have a linked list defined by CQ/Java code elsewhere in the code. That linked list is called `linkSet6`. Each 'node' in the list goes by the name `links`

I am trying to get the content from `linkSet6` to ArrayList `list6`.

The problem I am facing is `linkSet6` always exists but it may or may not have `links` in it. I am doing this and it works fine whenever there are "links"

```
if(currentNode != null && currentNode.hasNode("linkSet6")) {
   baseNode = currentNode.getNode("linkSet6").getNode("links");
   list6 = Utilities.parseStructuredMultifield(baseNode);
}
```

But when linkSet6 is emptyI get this error:

> org.apache.sling.api.scripting.ScriptEvaluationException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /apps/citrixosd-responsive/components/content/footerNavigation/footerNavigation.jsp at line 41

Line 41 is this:

```
baseNode = currentNode.getNode("linkSet6").getNode("links");
```

I've tried size(),length() etc to check but to no avail. Any tip on how to check if `links` exist before doing `getNode("links")`.

Comment: might be late, but we moved away from Node & Property to Resource & ValueMap to simplify code - especially in JSPs (which shouldn't build up data objects such as lists of maps).  See http://itgumby.github.io/blog/2016/better-aem-jsp-objects.html for more examples of the different APIs that simplify your code.

Answer (score 2):

You can validate if the node exists by using [Session.nodeExists(String)](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/api/1.6/org/apache/jackrabbit/api/jsr283/Session.html#nodeExists(java.lang.String)) method.

```
if (session.nodeExists(currentNode.getPath + "/linkSet6")) {
    ...
}
```

The session object is usually acquired via the `ResourceResolver` object: `resolver.adaptTo(Session.class)`

Anyway - I recommend jumping into the Sling abstraction layer. Working with `Resource` and `ResourceResolver` is bit more convenient in such case (e.g. `getResource` will return you a null when a resource does not exist).

Answer (score 1):

hasNode("links") will return true if the node links exists